# How to Access GPU Registers on Linux

Tags: c, linux, performance-testing, performancecounter, gpu

I'm attempting to access the GPU registers on an AMD HD7000 series card. I have sensors attached to the GPUs power input and consumption can be measured. I'd like to develop a Linux C++ application to access the performance counters of the GPU to assess power consumption based on GPU events/operations. I am familiar with C and C++, but I am not familiar with operating systems, and I'm not exactly sure where to get started for such a task.

I have a PDF. It is the Bios and Kernel Developers Guide to AMD 15h Family Models 30h-3Fh located here:
https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/49125_15h_Models_30h-3Fh_BKDG.pdf

In the linked document, on page 106, the performance counters are described. The counters must be set via a control register before they begin counting. On page 715, the counters are defined in more detail.

This document does not list the memory offset, so I checked the open source AMD Linux 4.14.12 drivers. Under /drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/sid.h line 1256, I found a performance counter address of 0x2688:

```
#define CB_PERFCOUNTER0_SELECT0     0x2688
```

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.12/source/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/sid.h#L1256

Also, a start and stop counter integer beginning line 1457:

```
#define PERFCOUNTER_START     (23 << 0)
#define PERFCOUNTER_STOP      (24 << 0)
```

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.12/source/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/sid.h#L1457

I'm assuming the CB_PERFCOUNTER defines are relevant addresses and can be used as an offset to the GPU's register memory location. I have searched on the internet very much, and there are many resources, although it is difficult for me to assess whether each resource has any relevant information or how any step fits into the process as a whole. Any direct explanations or references to material would be greatly appreciated.